# multiple workflow instances of Workflows with Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: windows, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm new to WF. what I'm trying to do is to create a simple Workflow Service and Call them in various clients. So what i have done, I have created a Workflow service. It has a xamlx file and that has a sequence with Receive and Send Reply activity. I also have Correlations. So the first ReceiveandSendReply activity has CanCreateInstance True. In addition to this I 
wrote some of my own code activities.

Now I have hosted this service is IIS and trying to call this service using a console app. I have added the web Reference and created a service client and passed the values to the service. It gives me expected results.

But when I'm trying to run another client at the same time it gives me Instance error. I think the Workflow is not initiating a new Instance for the second client.

So I did a search and found multiple instancing can be achieved by using workflowservicehost. But could not find a way to do it.

I think the way Im calling the service is not correct. I'm just creating a new object from the service reference and calling the operation.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please show some code (ideally a minimal, complete, and verifiable example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) and the actual error(s) you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at correlation rules you've set up for your workflow.  If several clients passes parameters which correlate with the same instance - a new instance won't be created.

So, if you need a new instance you either need to set different correlation rules, so that different client's calls would correlate with different workflow instances.

Comment: Yes it was something to do with Correlation. I have fixed it. Thanks for the reply. Im marking this as a correct answer.